# How to "restart" this script

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to code an Alarm System with the RPi.
I want that if you type the correct password that the script "restart"
This is the full code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import pygame
import itertools
import threading
import sys
import os


GPIO.setwarnings(False)

SENSOR_PIN = 23
rot = 4
gruen = 17
blau = 27

#GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(rot, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(gruen, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(blau, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(SENSOR_PIN, GPIO.IN)

def my_callback(channel):
 GPIO.output(rot, GPIO.LOW)
 GPIO.output(blau, GPIO.HIGH)
 print('Motion detected! 5 sek time.')
 time.sleep(5)
 pygame.init()
 pygame.mixer.music.load("alarm.mp3")
 pygame.mixer.music.play()
 alarmaus = input('ENTER CODE TO DISARM:')


 while True:
   GPIO.output(blau, GPIO.LOW)
   time.sleep(0.10)
   GPIO.output(blau, GPIO.HIGH)
   time.sleep(0.10)
   GPIO.output(blau, GPIO.LOW)
   time.sleep(0.10)

done = False
def animate():
    for c in itertools.cycle(['|', '/', '-', '\\']):
        if done:
            break
        sys.stdout.write('\rLoading... ' + c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1)
        sys.stdout.write('\rDONE! ')

t = threading.Thread(target=animate)
t.start()

time.sleep(5)
done = True
time.sleep(1)

sys.stdout.write('\rWillkommen\n ')

while True:
 GPIO.output(blau, GPIO.LOW)
 GPIO.output(rot, GPIO.LOW)
 GPIO.output(gruen, GPIO.LOW) 
 an = input('ENTER CODE TO ARM: ')   
 if an == '123':
  pygame.mixer.init()
 pygame.mixer.music.load("aktiv.mp3")
 pygame.mixer.music.play()
 GPIO.output(gruen, GPIO.HIGH)
 time.sleep(0.50)
 GPIO.output(gruen, GPIO.LOW)
 time.sleep(0.50)
 GPIO.output(gruen, GPIO.HIGH)
 time.sleep(0.50)
 GPIO.output(gruen, GPIO.LOW)
 time.sleep(0.50)
 GPIO.output(gruen, GPIO.HIGH)
 time.sleep(0.50)
 GPIO.output(gruen, GPIO.LOW)
 time.sleep(0.50)
 GPIO.output(gruen, GPIO.HIGH)
 time.sleep(0.50)
 GPIO.output(gruen, GPIO.LOW)
 time.sleep(0.50)
 GPIO.output(gruen, GPIO.HIGH)
 time.sleep(0.50)
 GPIO.output(gruen, GPIO.LOW)
 time.sleep(0.50)
 GPIO.output(gruen, GPIO.HIGH)
 time.sleep(0.50)
 GPIO.output(gruen, GPIO.LOW)
 time.sleep(1.00)
 GPIO.output(rot, GPIO.HIGH)
 print('ALARMSYSTEM ARMED')

 try:
    GPIO.add_event_detect(SENSOR_PIN , GPIO.RISING , callback=my_callback)
    while True:
        time.sleep(10)
 except KeyboardInterrupt:
     print ("Alarmanlage Deaktiviert")
 GPIO.cleanup()
```

if motion is detected you should enter a password to disarm the alarm and then you again should enter a password to arm the system.
but it dosnt work

I hope that you can help me

sorry for my bad english btw

Comment: By password do you mean `123`?

Comment: Put everything in a function and run it as often as you like.

Comment: @SamChats yes, i will change it later

Comment: @KlausD. thank you for help. it really works